# How to get access to Spark shell from Kubernetes?

Tags: bash, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I've used the [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spark) to deploy Spark to Kubernetes in GCE. According to default configuration in values.yaml the Spark is deployed to the path `/opt/spark`. I've checked that Spark has deployed successfully by running `kubectl --namespace=my-namespace get pods -l "release=spark"`. There is 1 master and 3 workers running.

However when I've tried to check Spark version by executing `spark-submit --version` from the Google cloud console it returned `-bash: spark-submit: command not found`.

I've navigated to the `/opt` directory and the `/spark` folder is missing. What should I do to be able to open Spark shell Terminal and to execute Spark commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify by checking service

`kubectl get services -n <namespace>`

you can port-forward particular service and try running locally to check

`kubectl port-forward svc/<service name> <external port>:<internal port or spark running port>`

Locally you can try running spark terminal it will be connected to spark running on GCE instance.

If you check the helm chart document there is also options for UI you can also do same to access UI via port-forward

> **Access via SSH inside  pod**

```
Kubectl exec -it <spark pod name> -- /bin/bash
```

here you can directly run spark commands. `spark-submit --version`

> **Access UI**

Access UI via port-forwarding if you have enable UI in helm chart.

`kubectl port-forward svc/<spark service name> <external port>:<internal port or spark running port>`

> **External Load balancer**

This particular helm chart also creating `External Load balancer` you can also get `External IP` using

`Kubectl get svc -n <namespace>`

> **Access Shell**

**If want to connect via LB IP & port**

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=<Load balancer IP> spark.cassandra-connection.native.port=<Port>
```

**Creating connection using port-forward**

`kubectl port-forward svc/<spark service name> <external(local) port>:<internal port or spark running port>`

```
./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=localhost spark.cassandra-connection.native.port=<local Port>
```

Comment: I've verified Spark is up and running with `kubectl get services -n <namespace>`. But how can I open Spark shell terminal and execute commands like `spark-submit --version`

Comment: you can ssh inside pod but that is not proper solution. kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- /bin/bash

Comment: This is a good question/answer. Can you expand your answer to show how to do this with both of your recommendations for the benefit of the K8s community?

Comment: @JohnHanley hi Jhon i have updated answer. Thank you for giving me opportunity.

Comment: @samba do kubectl get pods. `kubectl exec -it <spark pod name> -- /bin/bash` once ssh done inside pod here you can run the spark commands.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be login to pod and then run Spark commands

1. List the pod
   `kubectl --namespace=my-namespace get pods -l "release=spark"`
2. Now, Login to the pod using following command:
   `kubectl exec -it <pod-id> /bin/bash`
3. Now, you should be inside the pod and can run spark commands
   `spark-submit --version`

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/#getting-a-shell-to-a-container

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
spark-shell --master k8s://localhost:32217
```

My spark master is a LoadBalancer exposed at localhost:32217